# Azure - Node.js deployment fails: no such file package.tgz

Tags: node.js, git, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I set up a Node.js server within Azure like described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/

it worked well locally and @azure, I didnt deploy for one month to azure and only developed locally.

Now I again wanted to integrate my app to azure but after successfull commiting with Powershell:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some fixes"
git push azure master
```

I get: **Error extracting D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fs\0.0.0\package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory**

```
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 242 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '7ddb279f93'.
remote: Generating deployment script.
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling node.js deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Deleting file: 'iisnode.yml'
remote: Copying file: '_iisnode.yml'
remote: Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
remote: Using start-up script server.js
remote: Generated web.config.
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18,
0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.
1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6
.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0.
remote: Selected node.js version 4.2.3. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
remote: Selected npm version 3.5.1
remote: Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
remote: npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead
of jade
remote: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
remote: npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.2.3\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.5.1\\node_modu
les\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
remote: npm ERR! node v4.2.3
remote: npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
remote: npm ERR! code EREADFILE
remote:
remote: npm ERR! Error extracting D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fs\0.0.0\package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or direc
tory, open 'D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fs\0.0.0\package.tgz'
remote: npm ERR!
remote: Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\4.2.3\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.5.1\node
_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
remote: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
remote:
remote: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote: npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://XXX@xxxxxver.scm.azurewebsites.net/xxxxxxrver.git
   1a34e23..7ddb279  master -> master
PS D:\DEV\_Thesis\Thesis_RenegadeService\Node Renegade Server> git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in iisnode.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
PS D:\DEV\_Thesis\Thesis_xxxxxxrvice\Node xxxxxade Server> git commit -m "fixing"
[master 5a8a254] fixing
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in iisnode.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename _iisnode.yml => iisnode.yml (100%)
PS D:\DEV\_Thesis\Thesis_xxxxxervice\Node xxxxade Server> git push azure master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 233 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '5a8a2543a4'.
remote: Generating deployment script.
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling node.js deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Copying file: 'iisnode.yml'
remote: Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
remote: Using start-up script server.js
remote: Generated web.config.
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18,
0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.
1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6
.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0.
remote: Selected node.js version 4.2.3. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
remote: Selected npm version 3.5.1
remote: Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
remote: npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead
of jade
remote: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
remote: npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.2.3\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.5.1\\node_modu
les\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
remote: npm ERR! node v4.2.3
remote: npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
remote: npm ERR! code EREADFILE
remote:
remote: npm ERR! Error extracting D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fs\0.0.0\package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or direc
tory, open 'D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fs\0.0.0\package.tgz'
remote: npm ERR!
remote: Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\4.2.3\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.5.1\node
_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
remote: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
remote:
remote: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote: npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

It works locally on my machine...
Since last deployment I added

```
"passport": "*",
"fs": "*",
"passport-azure-ad": "*",
"cookie-parser": "*",
"express-session": "*",
"jade": "*",
"adal-node":"*"
```

And some code working with it.

Azure Portal says that everything went well but the deployment command. The error contains the above print.

Creating a new site with same code throws same error..

**EDIT:**
I browsed within the Azure directory to D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fs and there is no 0.0.0 directory, only a 0.0.2... how do I tell Azure now to use the 0.0.2 directory..

**EDIT2**
I fixed the problem (temporary) by setting the version of "fs" back to 0.0.0 in packages. Now I am not able to use higher versions...

Comment: To confirm,  `fs` module is part of node's core modules, why you need to additionally install it via npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adviced by "Gary Liu - MSFT" in the comment. Removing fs from packages has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try to force the node version in your package.json:

"engines": {
   "node": "6.6.0"
 }